# Facing Null Pointer Exception:Unable to run selenium script in Jenkins, but able to execute the script successfully in eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, nullpointerexception, testng

I am facing Null Pointer Exception while running selenium script with TestNG in Jenkins.

However, I am able to run the script successfully in Eclipse IDE locally.

Facing NullPointerException in printOutcome() method (@AfterMethod) and the error line is

String out = hm.get(testcaseName).toString();

Please help me to resolve the issue.

The code:

```
package com.expertus.admin_Administer_PEOPLE;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.expertus.libraries.Config;
import com.expertus.libraries.Generic;

public class CreateOrganization extends Config {

    @Test
    public void createOrganizationValidDataTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String moduleControllerPath = "./ModuleController/ModuleController.xlsx";
        String mainModule = Generic.getCellValue(moduleControllerPath, "Main", 1, 0);
        String es = Generic.getCellValue(moduleControllerPath, "Main", 1, 1);

        String testCaseName = Generic.getCellValue(moduleControllerPath, mainModule, 5, 0);
        String testcase_es = Generic.getCellValue(moduleControllerPath, mainModule, 5, 1);

        hm.put(testCaseName, "flag");
        if (es.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

            if (testcase_es.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                String testDataPath = "./test_data/Admin/Administer/People.xlsx";
                APP_LOGS.debug("***********************" + "TestCase " + " \" " + testCaseName + " \" "
                        + " starts executing " + "***********************");
                ps.signIN(CONFIG.getProperty("USERNAME"), CONFIG.getProperty("PASSWORD"), testCaseName, "SIGN-IN");
                ps.webdriverWaitVisibilityOfElementLocated(
                        "//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create Course']");
                ps.assertPage("//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create Course']", testCaseName,
                        "Courses and Classes");
                ps.clickPeople();
                ps.webdriverWaitVisibilityOfElementLocated(
                        "//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create User']");
                ps.assertPage("//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create User']", testCaseName,
                        "User");
                ps.clickOrganization();
                ps.webdriverWaitVisibilityOfElementLocated(
                        "//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create Organization']");
                ps.assertPage("//*[@id='narrow-search-actionbar-list']/li/a/span[text()='Create Organization']",
                        testCaseName, "Organization");

                int rc = Generic.getRowCount(testDataPath, testCaseName);

                for (int i = 1; i <= rc; i++) {

                    APP_LOGS.debug("***** Data Driving from row no :" + i + " *****");

                    ps.clickCreateOrgButton();
                    ps.assertPopUP("//span[text()='Organization']", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "ORGANIZATION");

                    String Name = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 0);
                    String Organization_Type = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 1);
                    String Cost_Center = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 2);
                    String Description = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 3);
                    String Parent_Organization = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 4);
                    String Contact = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 5);
                    String Label = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 6);
                    String Value = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 7);
                    String Access_Required = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 8);
                    String Groups_to_be_attached = Generic.getCellValue(testDataPath, testCaseName, i, 9);

                    System.out.println("Entering the Valid Data on Create-Organization popup");
                    APP_LOGS.debug("Entering the Valid Data on Create-Organization popup");

                    ps.clear("edit-name");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys(Name);
                    // ps.selectByVisibleText(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Type:']/following-sibling::div[1]/descendant::select")),
                    // Organization_Type);
                    ps.selectByVisibleText(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#edit-type")), Organization_Type);

                    ps.clear("edit-cost-center");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-cost-center")).sendKeys(Cost_Center);
                    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(
                            By.xpath("//div[text()='Description:']/following-sibling::div[1]/descendant::iframe")));
                    driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).sendKeys(Description);
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    ps.clear("edit-parent");
                    if (Parent_Organization.length() > 0) {
                        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-parent")).sendKeys(Parent_Organization);
                        ps.waitFor(1000l);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[text()='" + Parent_Organization + "']")).click();
                    }
                    ps.clear("edit-contact");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-contact")).sendKeys(Contact);
                    if (Label.length() > 0 && Value.length() > 0) {
                        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-add-customorg-custom-fields")).click();
                        ps.waitFor(2000l);
                        ps.clear("edit-custom-label-0");
                        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-custom-label-0")).sendKeys(Label);
                        ps.clear("edit-custom-value-0");
                        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-custom-value-0")).sendKeys(Value);
                    }
                    if (Access_Required.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        driver.findElement(By.id("visible-org-0")).click();
                        ps.waitFor(3000l);
                        driver.findElement(By.name("Administer")).click();
                        String actVal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='- Administer']")).getText();
                        String expVal = "- Administer";
                        ps.assertEqualsOnPOPUP(actVal, expVal, testCaseName, i);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[input[@id='edit-mrocancelbtn']]/div[3]/input[@name='op']"))
                                .click();
                        ps.waitFor(1500l);
                        String act = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='message-container']/div/ul/li/span"))
                                .getText();
                        String exp = "Details saved successfully.";
                        ps.assertEqualsOnPOPUP(act, exp, testCaseName, i);
                        driver.findElement(By.id("admin-bubble-close")).click();

                    }

                    ps.clickSaveButtonOrg();
                    String act_val = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='message-container']/div/ul/li/span"))
                            .getText();
                    String exp_val = "Details saved successfully.";
                    ps.assertEqualsOnPOPUP(act_val, exp_val, testCaseName, i);
                    driver.findElement(By.className("close")).click();
                    APP_LOGS.debug("***** Data Driving happened successfully from row no :" + i + " *****");
                    ps.waitFor(3000l);
                }

                ps.signOUT();

            }

        }

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void printOutcome() {
        String testcaseName = "CreateOrganization";
        String out = hm.get(testcaseName).toString();
        if (out.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
            hm.put(testcaseName, "PASS");
            System.out.println(testcaseName + " TestCase is PASSED");
            APP_LOGS.debug(testcaseName + " TestCase is PASSED");
        } else if (out.equalsIgnoreCase("SKIP")) {
            hm.put(testcaseName, "SKIP");
            System.out.println(testcaseName + " TestCase is SKIPPED");
            APP_LOGS.debug(testcaseName + " TestCase is SKIPPED");
        } else {
            hm.put(testcaseName, "FAIL");
            System.out.println(testcaseName + " TestCase is FAILED");
            APP_LOGS.debug(testcaseName + " TestCase is FAILED");
        }
    }

}
```

Config class:

```
package com.expertus.libraries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class Config {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static ProjectSpecific ps = null;
    public static Logger APP_LOGS = null;
    public static Properties CONFIG = null;
    public static Properties OR = null;
    public static HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    //public static String res;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void preCondition() throws IOException {


        APP_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Loading Property files");
        CONFIG = new Properties();
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "//src//com//expertus//config//config.properties");
        CONFIG.load(ip);

        OR = new Properties();
        ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "///src//com//expertus//config//OR.properties");
        OR.load(ip);
        APP_LOGS.debug("Loaded Property files successfully");

        String browserType = CONFIG.getProperty("browserType");

        if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("Mozilla"))
        {  
            File gecko = new File("/home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/lib/geckodriver");    
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", gecko.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println("Firefox Launching");
            APP_LOGS.debug("Launching Browser");
            Reporter.log("Opening Firefox", true);
        }
        else {
            String driverpath ="/home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/lib/chromedriver";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            options.merge(capabilities);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        }

        Generic.deleteRecursive(new File("/home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/Screenshot"));
        ps = new ProjectSpecific(driver, APP_LOGS, OR, CONFIG, hm);



    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuiteMethod() throws IOException {

        driver.quit();
        APP_LOGS.debug("Quits the session");

        Generic.writeRes("./ModuleController/ModuleController.xlsx", hm);

    }

}
```

The Output in Jenkins:

```
1574062510309   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 35651
1574062510409   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Nov 18, 2019 1:05:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Firefox Launching
Opening Firefox
Cleaning out folder:/home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/Screenshot
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 4.491 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] printOutcome(com.expertus.admin_Administer_PEOPLE.CreateOrganization)  Time elapsed: 0.016 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.expertus.admin_Administer_PEOPLE.CreateOrganization.printOutcome(CreateOrganization.java:151)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   CreateOrganization.printOutcome:151 NullPointer
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Jenkins job configuration:

[image: jenkins job configuration]

Jenkins Console Output after successfully executing the script

```
 java.lang.Error: 
Unresolved compilation problems: 
    BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field
    SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field
    BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field
    SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field
    BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field
    SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field


[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
```

My Generic.java file:

```
package com.expertus.libraries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

//import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class Generic {
    public static int getRowCount(String xlPath, String sheetName) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static String getCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static int getColumnCount(String xlPath, String sheetName, int rowNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getLastCellNum();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void setCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum, String cellVal) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Row r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum);
            if (r == null)
                r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).createRow(rowNum);
            Cell c = r.getCell(cellNum);
            if (c == null)
                c = r.createCell(cellNum);
            c.setCellValue(cellVal);
            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(xlPath);
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

    }

    public static void writeRes(String fisPath, HashMap hm) 
    {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fisPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

            Sheet mainSheet = wb.getSheet("Main");
            int rc = mainSheet.getLastRowNum();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rc; i++) {
                String module = mainSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)
                        .getStringCellValue();
                Sheet testCaseSheet = wb.getSheet(module);
                int rowCnt = testCaseSheet.getLastRowNum();
                for (int j = 1; j <= rowCnt; j++) {
                    String testcase = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(0)
                            .getStringCellValue();
                    Set<String> key = hm.keySet();
                    for (String k : key) {
                        if (testcase.equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
                            Cell c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(2);
                            if (c == null)
                                c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).createCell(2);
                            String value = hm.get(k).toString();
                            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont = wb.createFont();

                                headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
                                headerStyle
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());

                                headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("SKIP")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont2 = wb.createFont();

                                headerFont2.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle2.setFont(headerFont2);
                                headerStyle2
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());
                                headerStyle2.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle2);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont1 = wb.createFont();
                                headerFont1.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle1.setFont(headerFont1);
                                headerStyle1
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont1.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());
                                headerStyle1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle1);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream("./Results/Results " + curDate()
                    + ".xlsx");
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // returns current date with time
    public static String curDate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns current date
    public static String date() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns past date
    public static String past_furure_Date(int i) {
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -i);
        String pastDate = date.format(gc.getTime());
        return pastDate;
    }

    public static void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String name)
            throws IOException {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        //FileUtils
        //      .copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshot\\" + name + ".png"));

    }

    // to delete .png files in screenshot folder
    public static void deleteRecursive(File path) {
        File[] c = path.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Cleaning out folder:" + path.toString());
        for (File file : c) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Deleting file:" + file.toString());
                deleteRecursive(file);
                file.delete();
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What command are you using to run the test in jenkins. It has something to do with the classes that needs to be included in classpath. Ok check if you hardcoded any directory path .also you need to share Config class

Comment: Is your resource "/ModuleController/ModuleController.xlsx" not available on Jenkins? If the test fails before "hm.put(testCaseName, "flag");", your @AfterMethod will have a NPE

Comment: I am using "test" command to run the test.

Comment: I have updated my config class

Comment: I have attached my Jenkins job configuration. "/ModuleController/ModuleController.xlsx" is available in workspace location

Comment: Thanks Simon. I am able to execute the script successfully but the Jenkins console output displays: java.lang.Error: 
Unresolved compilation problems: 
 BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field
 SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field.                                    I have attached my Generic.java file . Please help me on this.I am using apache poi 4.1.1 and apache poi-ooxml 4.1.1